# Norm and boundedness of a linear operator

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $\ell^2 = {(x_1,x_2,..), x_n \in \mathbb{C} ; \sum^\infty_{i=1}|x_i|^2<\infty}$
and let $\|(x_1,x_2,..)\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2} $. Operator $M : \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ is defined as $M(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)= (x_2,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$. Can someone help please and explain how to show that $M$ is bounded and how to find its norm? Thanks in advance

So we need to find C, sucht that $||Ax||\leq C||x||$. So $||Ax|| = ||(x_2,x_2,x_3..)|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=2}^\infty|x_i| + |x_2|^2}$ and how to proceed next?

Comment: Any thoughts of your own you want to share?

Comment: the definition of $M$ has changed, is it $(x_1,x_1,x_2,...)$ or $(x_2,x_2,x_3,..)$

Comment: Why are you editing away your question?

Comment: Margarita. Do not deface the question by removing parts that are essential for others to evaluate it and the answers. That is against the site rules. You don't own the question in the sense that you would be allowed to do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

$\|M(x)\|=\sqrt{|x_2|^2+\|x\|^2-|x_1|^2}\leq \sqrt{2}\|x\|$ implies that $M$ is bounded, 
let $e_2=(0,1,0...0,..)$, $M(e_2)=(1,1,0,..0,..)$ implies that $\|M(e_1)\|=\sqrt2$, thus the norm is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it true that  $\|M(x)\|=\sqrt{|x_2|^2+\|x\|^2-|x_1|^2}\leq \sqrt{2}||x||$ ? The part with $\sqrt2$, could you explain please?

Comment: You have $|x_2|^2\leq \|x\|^2$ and $\|x\|^2-|x_1|^2\leq \|x\|^2$, you deduce that $|x_2|^2+\|x\|^2-|x_1|\leq 2\|x\|^2$.

Comment: certainly, what is that exercise?

Comment: you have to see that ${{2i+1}\over{i+1}}\leq 2$, so you can prove that $\|M(x)\|\leq 2\|x\|$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let 
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,..)= (x_2,0,0,..,0, ..) \\
S(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(0,x_2,x_3,....)$$

Show that both $T,S$ are bounded and use the fact that $M=T+S$ to deduce that $M$ is bounded.